# Cells and pointers variables

Tags: java, pointers

```
class Cell<T> {
    T first;
    Cell<T> next;
    Cell(T f,Cell<T> n) {
       first=f;
       next=n;
    }
}
```

Suppose we have three variables ls1, ls2 and ptr of type `Cell<Character>` and the cells and-pointers diagram below gives the initial situation:
[image]

Draw the cells-and-pointers diagram which would represent the situation after the following lines
of code have been executed:

```
ls2.next.first='z';
ls1.next=ls1.next.next;
for(ptr=ls2; ptr!=null; ptr=ptr.next)
ls1 = new Cell(ptr.first,ls1);
```

**Attempt:**
After the first line b is changed to z.
After the second line y is changed to z.
But i'm not sure if that is right or what happens next.

Comment: java doesn't have pointers. It has references

Comment: I know but the question asks to draw a cells and pointer diagram

Comment: `y` is not changed to `z` instead `x.next => z` and `y` is discarded.

Comment: Java does have pointers, it just doesn't have explicit pointers.  Consider the existence of Null**Pointer**Exception.

Comment: @SteveChaloner an unfortunate legacy rather than by design.  Java doesn't have pointers, nor does the JVM it is built on, despite this name.

Comment: I think using the name "first" is misleading. What you actually have is `T data` and `Cell<T> next`.

Comment: @SteveChaloner I agree. The OP should think of it as the node/cell's data not the first of anything.

Comment: @SteveChaloner I think the quote is "Today is the first day of the rest of your life" ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey from the VM docs: "An "oop", or ordinary object pointer in Java Hotspot parlance, is a managed pointer to an object...Managed pointers in the Java heap point to objects which are aligned on 8-byte address boundaries" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the first part. The line `ls2.next.first='z';` would change your lists to be:

```
ls1 --> x --> y --> z --> c
ls2 --> a ---------^
```

You basically change the *value* of the cell.

Then, the second line `ls1.next=ls1.next.next;` would discard the y element of the first list:

```
ls1 --> x --> z --> c
ls2 --> a ---^
```

And then you have a for loop. Inside this loop you run over all the elements of ls2 and create **new** elements at the head of ls1, as such:

```
ls1 --> a --> x --> z --> c
ls2 --> a ---------^

ls1 --> z --> a --> x --> z --> c
ls2 --> a ---------------^

ls1 --> c --> z --> a --> x --> z --> c
ls2 --> a ---------------------^
```

Note that when you create these new cells, you pass their value (for some reason in your code called `first`) to the constructor, thus creating completely new object which are not connected.

Answer (score 0):

ls1 = czaxzc
ls2 = azc
Below you have the code in Java.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell<Character> c = new Cell<>('c',null);
        Cell<Character> b = new Cell<>('b',c);
        Cell<Character> y = new Cell<>('y',b);
        Cell<Character> x = new Cell<>('x',y);
        Cell<Character> a = new Cell<>('a',b);


        Cell<Character> ls1 = x;
        Cell<Character> ls2 = a;



        ls2.next.first = 'z';
        ls1.next = ls1.next.next;
        for (Cell ptr = ls2; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
            ls1 = new Cell(ptr.first, ls1);
        }

        print(ls1);
        print(ls2);

    }

    public static void print(Cell list) {
        for (Cell ptr = list; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
            System.out.print(ptr.first);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    static class Cell<T> {
        T first;
        Cell<T> next;

        Cell(T f, Cell<T> n) {
            first = f;
            next = n;
        }
    }

}
```